# How to append values to a python dictionary and return it in a function call

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, return

I have a for loop within a python function call that executes a number of times. I need to return the values in a dictionary to dump them into a db.

Here is a piece of sample code, how can I append values to a dictionary and ensure I have all of them for further use.

```
def parser_code():
    log = dict()
    for i in range(len):
        log['abc'] = 2*i
        log['xyz'] = 10+i
    return log
```

This will execute atleast twice so I want a dictionary to be log = `{['abc':2, 'xyz':11],['abc':3, 'xyz':12]}`

How can I append to the result each time?  Or is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: The syntax of your expected answer is odd. Do you want `log` to be a list type, and not a dict? So that `log = [{'abc':2, 'xyz':11},{'abc':3, 'xyz':12}]`?

Comment: It can be a dict, I just want to append all the results of the for loop into it.

Comment: The thing is, dictionaries don't work like that in Python. You can set the value of a key of a dictionary, but "appending" isn't a feature of dicts.

Comment: To get a clearer idea what you want to have in the function result, maybe explain what you want to do later with it. Then someone could provide an answer with a fitting data structure for the result.

Comment: I will be storing these in a sqlite db. The 'abc' and 'xyz' are actually information pertaining to a running instance of a server so they can be for different servers or just at different time periods.

Comment: the "len" in the range parameter to the for loop is an undefined variable

Comment: yeah this was a sample code - I should pass it in my function call. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what behavior you're expecting, but I think this code should suffice:

```
def parser_code(length):
  log = list()
  for i in range(length):
    this_dict = dict()
    this_dict['abc'] = 2*i
    this_dict['xyz'] = 10+i
    log.append(this_dict)
  return log
```

Comment: yes this worked, thanks a lot! I guess I was referring to something like this!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `defaultdict` part of std-libs.

```
from collections import defaultdict
glog = defaultdict(list)
def parser_code(dd):
    for i in range(length):
        dd['abc'].append(2*i)
    return dd

glog = parser_code(glog)
```

if you actually want to use your result you have to have make sure that the dict is not created new for every call to your function.

still a bit unclear if you need a dict or not, you will only need that if you want the ability for key-lookup. If you are happy with just making a list (array) of numbers, then go ahead and use a list.

```
glog = list()
def parser_code(lst):
    return lst + [2*i for i in range(length)]
glog = parser_code(glog)
```

Comment: This is exactly what he wants yes instead of building his own custom dictionary

Comment: Wow thanks. I did not know about `defaultdict`, this is helpful too for my usecase!

Answer (score -1):

you can give the dictionary as a parameter to your function.

please not that your code is not working for me (original indention of the for loop - it's corrected now) and the len parameter). I needed to guess a little bit what you are actually doing. Could you take a look at your example code in the question or comment here?

```
def parser_code(result, length):
   for i in range(length):
       result['abc'] = 2*i
       result['xyz'] = 10+i
   return result

d = {}
parser_code(d, 3)
print(d)
parser_code(d, 3)
print(d)
```

will give this output:

```
python3 ./main.py 
{'abc': 4, 'xyz': 12}
{'abc': 4, 'xyz': 12}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers his question.

Comment: Ok, so it does avoid resetting the dict on each call actually, but it's still not the structure they are asking for

Comment: yes, you would be working with the existing dict, not a new one, every time.

Comment: thanks for responding I was looking for something a little different - to add the values to the same dictionary each time and then return them all.